# php / js - how do I delete a file when the page unloades?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload

I have an issue here, I'm not sure if it's possible but I would like to delete a file when the user leaves the page... I currently have a php script (*see below*) which handels the deleting of a file, but i don't know how to run it when the page unloads?

```
<?php
include 'js/db/db.php';
$film = $_GET['film'];
$movie = $_GET['org_film'];
$user = $_COOKIE['user'];
$filename = "movies/".$user."/".$film.".mp4";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    header('location: storage.php');
}
else{
    $filename = "movies/".$user."/".$film.".m4v";
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
        header('location: storage.php');
    }
    else{
        echo " file doesn't Exist"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The short answer is you can't, because you can't reliably catch the event of a user leaving a page. You may need to implement a cleanup script that frequently removes older files

Comment: okay, but lets say `window.onbeforeunload` is reliable, how would I go from there?

Comment: there is an event `window.onunload` which you could use to call an AJAX request to the PHP file. As @Pekka it won't be overly reliable and a cleanup script is a much better method

Comment: okay, I'll try an ajax request :)

Comment: Lenny - `window.onbeforeunload` isn't reliable at all in this case, as your Ajax request won't make it through in time. You'd have to use a blocking request, but I'm not sure whether that is even possible in all browsers. I'd go for a cleanup script.

Comment: I would do a cleanup script, but I would really prefer being able to delete the file when the user leaves, the reason for this is that I am getting a film from my external hd via ftp and then watch it, but this obviously means putting the file in a temp folder, I would like the file to get delete when the user finishes watching the film, If I fire a periodic cleanup script the user may be watching the film when the file gets deleted...

Comment: @Lenny - It is like a school - you employ a caretaker to do this. Tidy up after the children have had their fun. Just get a script to run periodically to fidy the file system (playground) up. Use `cron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like you're creating a temporary file so that you can deliver a video to a specific user for a specific amount of time. This is a highly inefficient approach. You'd be better off:

1. Using your database to track which users have access to which videos, and how how long
2. On a request to the video page, assert that the user has the right to access that file and, if the assertion passes, generate a *signed url* which is valid only for a short period of time and which may be used in the video page to deliver your movie.

A signed URL would look something like:

```
http://path.to/your/movie.m4v?timestamp=2309583240&signature=234p9345u234234092wjdfl
```

Where timestamp is the current UNIX timestamp and signature is a SHA1 hash of the timestamp and some secret known only to your application.

Amazon S3 supports this feature - you could also store the movie files on Amazon S3 with limited read privileges, and use one of the many popular S3 libraries to generate time-limited signed URLs for your users.

This would obviate the need to shift large files around the disk, and thereby greatly increase performance. It would also scale better as the maximum concurrent viewers would no longer by tied to disk size.

Comment: That's given me a pretty good idea, and you where right with it being a temp file, but the user gets to pick if its temp or not

Comment: The key is not needing to create a copy of the file for every user. If the data is shared between every user, there is no need to do this. Storage is cheap, but it ain't that cheap :)

Answer (score 1):

Your main script/app must track user activity storing in a DB every server request.

Run a php script scheduled by a cron job every x minutes that ask to DB for last user activity (date/time). Delete files after y minutes of no activity.

Is just an idea.